# character type int

Tags: c, character-encoding

A character constant has type `int` in C.

Now suppose my machine's local character set is Windows Latin-1 ( http://www.ascii-code.com/) which is a 256 character set so every `char` between single quotes, like `'x'`, is  mapped to an `int` value between 0 and 255 right ?

Suppose plain `char` is `signed` on my machine and consider the following code:

```
char ch = 'â'

if(ch == 'â')  
{
    printf("ok");
}
```

Because of the integer promotion `ch` will be promoted into a negative
quantity of type `int` (cause it has a leading zero) and being`â` mapped to a positive
quantity `ok` will not be printed.

But I'm sure i'm missing something ,  can you help ?

Comment: if (ch == 'â') [...] ch instead of c under if clause

Comment: Isn't your character outside of that character set?  I see it as a multi-byte character.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato I don't get this point , â is mapped to int qunatity 226 so it is within byte bounds.

Comment: What comes out if you `printf("%d", (int)'â');` ?

Comment: Ok, it comes out differently on my system.  I see it having value 50082.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you use '\342'?

Comment: @Vaughn Cato I don't actually have such a machine.

Comment: @user986437: When I use '\342' to get a character with an integer value of 226, this actually has an integer value of -30, so I would expect your comparison to still work.

Comment: The way â is encoded depends on your editor. With a good one, you should be able to configure it (search for encoding / code page / character set / locale...)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the initial assignment will not work as expected:

```
char ch = 'â';
```

There's an overflow here, and gcc will warn about it. Technically, this is undefined behavior, although  for the very common single-byte `char` type, the behavior is  predictable enough -- it's a simple integer overflow. Depending on your default character set, that's a multibyte character; I get decimal 50082 if I print it as an integer on my machine.

Furthermore, the comparison is invalid, again because `char` is too small to hold the value being compared, and again, a good compiler will warn about it.

ISO C defines `wchar_t`, a type wide enough to hold extended (i.e., non-ASCII) characters, along with wide character versions of many library functions. Code that must deal with non-ASCII text should use this wide character type as a matter of course.

Comment: Undefined behavior as with integer overflow?

Comment: This depends on your default character set and your compiler, I suppose, but for many folks that's a multi-byte character. If I print the integer value I actually get 50082 , which is much too big for an int.

Comment: why overflow ? as I said â is mapped to int qunatity 226 so it is within byte bounds.

Comment: @user986437 C only uses 7 bits of a character byte, so the largest value for an ascii character is 7F - 127.

Comment: *Technically, this is undefined behavior* This is not UB, assignment expressions never overflow because integer conversions apply.

Comment: now the question is: is an extended-ascii character (i.e. [0,255]) considered a non ascii-character ?

Comment: For those who are wondering where 50082 came from: 50082 = 0xC3A2 = UTF-8 encoding of `â`.

Answer (score 1):

Your C implementation has a notion of an *execution character set*. Moreover, if your program source code is read from a file (as it always is), the compiler has (or should have) a notion of a *source character set*. For example, in GCC you can tune those parameters on the command line. The combination of those two settings determines the integral value that is assigned to your literal  `â`.

Answer (score 0):

In a case where `char` is signed:

When processing `char ch = 'â'`, the compiler will convert â to 0xFFFFFFE2, and store 0xE2 in ch. There is no overflow, as the value is signed.

When processing `if(ch == 'â')`, the compiler will extend ch (0xE2) to integer (0xFFFFFFE2) and compare it to 'â' (0xFFFFFFE2 also), so the condition will be true.